# How to set up the room for HTC Vive with Elite Dangerous

Tags: elite-dangerous, vive

Maybe this is obvious once I get everything, but right now I'm waiting for my HTC Vive to arrive and wondering about what should I do to have the best room set up.

I have a couch/TV area where Elite Dangerous is likely to be played and next to it I have an empty space for other standing up games.

Should my room setup overlap the couch so I can sit on it to play Elite Dangerous? Can I have two rooms set up? Does the room even matter for Elite Dangerous?

Answer (score 2):

Coming from [Steam Support](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2001-UXCM-4439):

> - Pick a room with some free space. For Room Scale VR, you will need at least 2m x 1.5m (or 6.5 ft. x 5ft.). The maximum distance supported
>     between base stations is 5m (or 16 ft).
> - Make sure you have some room overhead, as some experiences may have you reaching above your head.
> - Your VR area should be clear of furniture and pets – look for two corners of the room (or high bookshelves) opposite each other that
>     have a good view of this VR area. This is where you will set up your
>     base stations.

They also provide some examples of how it should be setup, with the small rectangles in the corners as the base stations:

[image: Vive setup examples]

Now if you're going to be sitting to play this game (which for Elite Dangerous, you probably will be), see step 6 in that link.  There is a room setup option, where you select if you will be playing **room scale** or **standing** (which is also for sitting).  Follow the instructions, and set it up to your liking.

I think the difficult thing is going to be setting up the base stations so that it can detect you as you move both during room-scale experiences and sitting/standing experiences.  The support page says that you want two corners of the room that are opposite of one another, however you may have to change the locations of some of the stations, but that's really something you'll have to find out once you get the Vive.

Comment: Wow, what an answer. Thank you so much! Can the standing/sitting area be between the lighthouses but outside the virtual playing room (or however you call it)?

Comment: @J.PabloFernández I found a [Steam post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/358040/discussions/0/365163686062910072/) that says: "As long as the blocks can detect the Vive then you shouldn't have a problem playing games like elite dangerous, because all the Vive needs to do is be able to talk to them, so it can say when its location changes."

Answer (score 1):

I play Elite Dangerous on Vive. I just use an xbox 360 controller and sit in my chair with the headset on. There is no walking so no need for a "room" per se. Just make sure you have one Vive controller handy to "reset seated position" when you start unless your chair is fixed to the floor and you never slouch.

To answer "Can the standing/sitting area be between the lighthouses but outside the virtual playing room (or however you call it)?" Yes, I do it.

Comment: "There is no walking" ...yet. ;-)